# Deleting all nested data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have four **models**: `Subject` > `Topic` > `Content` > `Block`.

- When deleting a `Subject` I also want to delete the nested `Topic`, `Content` and `Block`.
- When deleting a `Topic` I want to delete the nested `Content` and `Block`.
- When deleting a `Content` I want to delete the nested `Block`.

How should I do that?

Comment: What have you tried, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Why are you guys voting me down. That makes me sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to put this in the comments, but its too small to see. I don't recommend forcing CoreData I think the problem may be somewhere else and I would definitely give it some thought. But in a pinch you can just delete the references.

I think this code is right:

```
        func delete(_ item: NSManagedObject) {
        let context = item.managedObjectContext!
        
        switch item.entity.name {
            case .some("Subject"):
                (item as! Subject).topic.forEach({delete($0)})

            case .some("Topic"):
                (item as! Topic).content.forEach({delete($0)})

            case .some("Content"):
                (item as! Content).block.forEach({delete($0)})

            default:
                break
        }
       
        context.delete(item)
    }
```

I don't have a quick way to test right now.
But something recursive like this would probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

Click on your xcdatamodel file. Click on the relationship you want. Click on the inspector and select a delete rule. In your case you want to cascade down from Subject>Topic etc. so just select cascade from each one.

[image]

In the inspector on the Delete Rule Drop down menu pick cascade.

[[image: ]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IECiB.png)

Comment: I did this. But it deleted some data here and there. :-(

Comment: I want to do it manually with full control!

Comment: Hmm I suspect the issue may be somewhere else, CoreData is pretty good at managing the database.. There is only one way I know to delete them manually and that would be to fetch them in order and delete or otherwise gather all their ids and delete. I will say if you're stoping in the debugger a lot and restarting some things may not be getting saved. You may want to tell the context to save after deletion, if you're going to be hitting a break point.

Comment: @TimoMüller "But it deleted some data here and there" - that definitely should be investigated! As SeaSpell pointed out already: "I suspect the issue may be somewhere else".